# Regex pattern equality

Tags: scala, equality, scalatest

In ScalaTest, I have the following check:

```
"abc".r shouldBe "abc".r
```

But it is not equal. I don't understand.

```
abc was not equal to abc
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.ing.cybrct.flink.clickstream.ConfigsTest$$anonfun$6 at (ConfigsTest.scala:97)
Expected :abc
Actual   :abc
```

Comment: `"abc".r == "abc".r` is also false in the REPL so it's not scalatest-specific

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's [possible to decide whether two regular expressions accept the same language](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5058.pdf), it seems to be rather complicated and not all that terribly useful for everyday regex usage. Therefore, equality on compiled regex patterns is just referential equality:

```
val x = "abc".r
val y = "abc".r
x == y
// res0: Boolean = false
```

Comment: So there is no way in scalatest, that we can test whether two regex are value equal?

Comment: can we do this: `"abc".r.toString() shouldBe "abc".r.toString()`

Comment: however, *"In Scala, at least on the JVM, == simply calls equals"*, which is actually not referential equality.

Comment: @fluency03 Instead of calling `toString()`, you can just ask whether `x.regex == y.regex`, because `.regex` already contains the string representation from which the compiled pattern was generated. That would be a "cheap" intensional equality that to some degree approximates the "interesting" extensional equality. For `regex`, `equals` simply redirects to `eq`, which is referential equality.

Answer (score 5):

The method `shouldBe` in Scalatest 3.0.5 delegates the equality check to the `areEqualComparingArraysStructurally` method:

```
def shouldBe(right: Any): Assertion = {
  if (!areEqualComparingArraysStructurally(leftSideValue, right)) {
    val (leftee, rightee) = Suite.getObjectsForFailureMessage(leftSideValue, right)
    val localPrettifier = prettifier // Grabbing a local copy so we don't attempt to serialize AnyShouldWrapper (since first param to indicateFailure is a by-name)
    indicateFailure(FailureMessages.wasNotEqualTo(localPrettifier, leftee, rightee), None, pos)
  }
  else indicateSuccess(FailureMessages.wasEqualTo(prettifier, leftSideValue, right))
}
```

which in turn simply delegates the equality check (as you can expect) to the `==` operator:

```
private[scalatest] def areEqualComparingArraysStructurally(left: Any, right: Any): Boolean = {
  // Prior to 2.0 this only called .deep if both sides were arrays. Loosened it
  // when nearing 2.0.M6 to call .deep if either left or right side is an array.
  // TODO: this is the same algo as in scalactic.DefaultEquality. Put that one in
  // a singleton and use it in both places.
  left match {
    case leftArray: Array[_] =>
      right match {
        case rightArray: Array[_] => leftArray.deep == rightArray.deep
        case _ => leftArray.deep == right
      }
    case _ => {
      right match {
        case rightArray: Array[_] => left == rightArray.deep
        case _ => left == right
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Scala, at least on the JVM, `==` simply calls `equals`, which, if not overridden, checks whether the compared variables point to the same object. `case class`es are peculiar in that the compiler overrides `equals` for you to compare the constructor arguments.

You can test it very easily with the following (but as you can imagine, the same applies to simply using `==` on your own):

```
package org.example

import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

final class MyClass(val a: Int)

final case class MyCaseClass(a: Int)

final class TestSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "equality on case classes" should "succeed" in {

    new MyCaseClass(1) shouldBe new MyCaseClass(1)

  }

  "equality on non-case classes" should "fail" in {

    new MyClass(1) shouldNot be(new MyClass(1))

  }

  "equality between Regex objects" should "fail" in {

    "abc".r shouldNot be("abc".r)

  }

}
```

What the `r` method does is instantiating a new `Regex` object, which is not a `case class` and does not override the equality definition, thus yielding the result you see.

Comment: That's what I meant to say but I can see my explanation was farraginous, I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Maybe "literally the same chunk of memory" or something like that? "Literally the same" is still somehow ambiguous, because it defines the yet-to-be-defined notion of "equality" through equally undefined notion of "sameness". Moreover, the word "literally" could invoke the impression that it's more about the syntactic shape of the code that describes the object, rather than about its memory location. That's why I like the phrase "referential equality" - at least, it's a thing that's more or less universally understandable. I'm nitpicking, I know. ;)

Comment: `the compared variables point to the same object` should do it, hopefully.

Comment: So there is no way in scalatest, that we can test whether two regex are value equal?

Comment: @fluency03 Just convert the regexes back to strings. Note that two regexes might represent the same pattern but their string representation might not be equal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are not equal. Both `"abc".r`  are  different references to two different memory locations. *shouldbe* is to  check **`equality`**  but not **`identity`**.

Comment: This is not really so. For example `val (a,b)=(Some(1), Some(1))` are also two different references, yet `a == b` is true ...

Comment: "abc".r == "abc".r ... it will return false.

Comment: Exactly. In both cases they are different memory locations, but the result is true in one case, but false in the other.